# how to remove top border from rviz::Panel

Tags: rviz, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I remove the top area from a custom rviz plugin?

For example, how do I remove the top area with minimize and close button for [TeleopPanel](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/rviz_plugin_tutorials/html/panel_plugin_tutorial.html). This is the case for Tools, but its not a QWidget

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201027/how-to-remove-top-border-from-rviz::panel/) by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 528 on 2015-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best way to go forward with customization is to use rviz as a library http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/librviz_tutorial/html/index.html

---

Originally posted by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) with karma: 528 on 2015-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0